# Why isn't Django creating a foreign key for my model?

Tags: sql, django

My model code is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 150)

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

running

```
python manage.py sqlall yabe
```

Results in

```
Mac-mini:yabedjango hn$ python manage.py sqlall yabe
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "yabe_post" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "text" varchar(150) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "yabe_comment" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "text" varchar(150) NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
Mac-mini:yabedjango hn$
```

I was expecting a foreign key in yabe_comment. Python version:

```
Python 2.7.4 (v2.7.4:026ee0057e2d, Apr  6 2013, 11:43:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Django version:

```
django-admin.py --version
1.5.1
```

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the entire output, after the semicolon there should be something like this `ALTER TABLE 'yabe_comment' ADD CONSTRAINT '...' FOREIGN KEY ('post_id') REFERENCES 'yabe_post' ('id');`

Comment: Yes I have. After COMMIT; I just have the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the whole output. I copied your model and tried. The whole output of command:
`manage.py sqlall app_name` is:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `head_post` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `text` varchar(150) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE `head_comment` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `text` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `post_id` integer NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE `head_comment` ADD CONSTRAINT `post_id_refs_id_b2b5e564` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `head_post` (`id`);
CREATE INDEX `head_comment_87a49a9a` ON `head_comment` (`post_id`);

COMMIT;
```

PS. `head` is the app name I am using.

Comment: This is what user2298943 already suggested, so not really an answer. The OP should probably specify more detailed environmental information

Comment: I have modified the post to include environment information.  I have copied and pasted verbatim

Comment: That's really strange. I am using the same Python and Django version you are using. Run ./manage.py syncdb and go to mysql terminal to confirm whether foreign keys are created or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py sql yabe
```

You can see `"post_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "blog_post" ("id")`

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "blog_post" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "text" varchar(150) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "blog_comment" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "text" varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    "post_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "blog_post" ("id")
)
;
```

i think it helped you